# Do there exist $C>0$ and $\alpha>0$ such that $|\hat{f}(n)|<\dfrac{C}{n^{\alpha}}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, upper-lower-bounds

Let $f:\mathbb{T}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a continuous functions.

**Question**
Do there exist $C>0$ and $\alpha>0$ such that

$$|\hat{f}(n)|<\dfrac{C}{n^{\alpha}}$$

I feel like this should be true however i don't even know where to start. I would like some hint on where to begin!

Comment: It might help to know that bounds like this are related to the smoothness properties of the original function $f$. See for example here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Magnitude_of_Fourier_coefficients. The results on this page follow from the Weierstrass $M$-test.

Comment: Thank you! I'll post if i can derive the answer

Comment: The answer to the question is "No". One way to show this (if you know some functional analysis) is the closed graph theorem.